# La relación entre “Nena, no te peines en la cama” y “Que los viajantes se van a atrasar”

Tags: significado-en-contexto

No entiendo por qué en la canción “[Lamento Boliviano](https://www.google.com/search?q=Enanitos%20Verdes%20-%20Lamento%20Boliviano%20letras&sxsrf=ALiCzsZLO6s0sXZy8q7flL8Vcvf1B00Fsw%3A1665271543185&ei=9wZCY8r6Cp7l0PEPktS_qAU&ved=0ahUKEwiK0qT249H6AhWeMjQIHRLqD1UQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=Enanitos%20Verdes%20-%20Lamento%20Boliviano%20letras&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEB4QFjIGCAAQHhAWMgYIABAeEBYyBggAEB4QFjIGCAAQHhAWMgYIABAeEBYyBggAEB4QFjIGCAAQHhAWMgYIABAeEBYyBggAEB4QFjoKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzoHCAAQgAQQEzoICAAQHhAWEBM6CggAEB4QFhAKEBM6CQgAEIAEEA0QE0oECEEYAEoECEYYAFCLAljQCGDoCWgBcAF4AIABoAGIAekFkgEDNC4zmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz)” se aconseja a la nena no peinarse porque los viajantes se van a demorar. O sea, no entiendo la relación entre las dos frases. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: [Nena no te peines en la cama](https://www.losandes.com.ar/sociedad/nena-no-te-peines-en-la-cama-que-significa-la-iconica-frase-del-hit-de-los-enanitos-verdes/) por la superstición de que trae mala suerte, otros dicen que es peinar [peinar: picar la cocaína y hacer líneas con ésta](https://books.google.cl/books?id=QhebSRevtqMC&pg=PA298&lpg=PA298&dq=peinar+coca%C3%ADna&source=bl&ots=Sp3lu1iBEG&sig=ACfU3U1cvxyAivXxW1IqrJ-bFzu1vK0HnA&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9rbvb-NH6AhUWBLkGHeGsDqIQ6AF6BAgjEAM), pero ahí estaría mal usado porque en peinarse el complemento directo estaría usado como reflexivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**¡Nena, no te peines en la cama que los viajantes se van a atrasar!.**

Existen varias teorías sobre su origen;

- 1. hace alusión al viaje realizado por la banda "Alcohol Etílico" a Perú, su inspiración vino de los inmigrantes bolivianos.
- 2. Como homenaje a los inmigrantes bolivianos en Argentina.
- 3. Inspirada en algunos versos del libro "Crónica de una muerte anunciada" de Gabriel García Márquez.

---

- 4. Engaños y deslealtades por parte de la chica, a pesar de lo cual, el chico continua entregado y amando a esa mujer en una relación tóxica y dependiente de la que le es imposible escapar.

---

La interpretación no es fácil ya que ni los propios autores han querido desvelarla. Aquí dejo unas cuantas ideas por si sirven de algo.

---

**Rasgos Generales**

Realmente la canción no es de Enanitos Verdes o de Hombres G como algunos piensan, sino de una banda argentina anterior llamada "Alcohol Etílico", compuesta por Raúl Federico y Natalio Faingold en 1984 y que la lanzó en su disco "Envasado en Origen" de 1986 y que en un principio llevaba como título "Soy como una roca" (Lamento Boliviano) . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4mGsEMIJTA

El contacto posterior de Dimi Bass (Raúl Federico) con otros músicos relacionados con otra banda argentina llamada "Enanitos verde", harían posible una revisión de los arreglos, como la nueva atmósfera andina incorporada para al final, grabarla dentro de su séptimo álbum "Big bang" del 15 de Agosto de 1994 . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0A0d5f1eNhQ

---

"**Crónica de una muerte anunciada**"

La agrupación musical de esta banda nunca se ha pronunciado sobre las las interpretaciones que se han querido dar a la frase "**Nena, no te peines en la cama que los viajantes se van a atrasar**", sin embargo, según las teorías más cercanas parece que parte de esta letra se encuentra basada en algunas de las ideas y frases que el escritor Gabriel García Márquez vierte en "**Crónica de una muerte anunciada**", aunque se desconoce si es verdad, coincidencia o solo se encuentra en el subconsciente de las personas a la hora de componer.

Así vemos que en la canción aparece;

**Soy como una roca**

**Palabras no me tocan**

palabras utilizadas en el libro de Márquez y que dieron lugar a parte del título original y de la letra de esta melodía.

y aquellas otras que relacionan "**Nena, no te peines en la cama que los viajantes se van a atrasar**"  con aquella antigua costumbre de peinarse en la cama antes de ir a dormir y que esta enlazada con atraer la mala suerte sobre sí o sobre los seres queridos.

> Lo único que mi madre les reprochaba era la costumbre de **peinarse**
> **antes de dormir**. -**Muchachas**- les decía -**No se peinen de noche que se
> retrasan los navegantes**-. Salvo por eso, pensaba que no había hijas
> mejor educadas. -Son perfectas- le oía decir con frecuencia.

**Nena**, (muchachas), **no te peines en la cama** (no se peinen de noche) **que los viajantes se van a atrasar** (que se retrasan los navegantes).

Se ve claro el paralelismo entre **navegantes** (marineros) y **viajantes** (viajeros) en esta parte y el retraso o tardanza de los mismos.

La antigua superstición indicaba que la persona que se cepillaba o peinaba el pelo antes de irse a dormir (a la cama) podría atraer la mala suerte en aquellos seres queridos que se encontraban en alta mar, teniendo contratiempos y percances y por tanto, **retrasando** su vuelta o llegada a puerto  y al encuentro con ellos. Posteriormente esta superstición se extendió no solo a marineros sino a todo aquel que viajara o se desplazara.

---

Así, en el contexto de la narrativa de la canción y al ser éste un "lamento por un desamor o amor roto", un "**lamento boliviano**", es decir, una queja continua sobre algo, en este caso una queja continua por la perdida de un amor,

**"Nena, no te peines en la cama que los viajantes se van a atrasar"**

según esta teoría, se podría convertir en **un aviso** para la chica que vendría a decir, "Chica, *no te peines en la cama*, es decir, no sigas actuando u obrando de esa manera, pues sabes que eso trae mala suerte y los nuevos amores (navegantes, marineros, viajantes, viajeros), nunca llegarán a tu puerto, es decir a ti, nunca más te enamoraras, o simplemente el amor se retrasara mucho en el tiempo para ti. Hoy en día diríamos, "y el Karma o el Universo se vengarán de ti".

---

**Interpretación viendo el video**

En líneas generales es la historia de un desamor continuado y a la vez, un amor dependiente que se convierte en un sufrimiento constante y desgarrado para el protagonista de la melodía, pues se convierte en una marioneta o títere en las manos de ella, siendo la frase;

"**¡Nena, no te peines en la cama que los viajantes se van a atrasar!**"

una especie de ironía donde pone de relieve el carácter caprichoso y un tanto promiscuo de la chica de la que esta totalmente entregado y que viene a decir, "Nena, hay muchos viajantes (hombres) que desean peinarte en la cama (estar contigo) y vas hacer que se retrasen (y no puedas estar con todos)", aún así él narrador de la canción sigue irremediable e inevitablemente enamorado de ella, sufriendo por dentro como ese "Lamento Boliviano" (queja o daño continuo).

---

***Interpretación Letra Lamento Boliviano***

> Me quieren agitar (**Ellos me quieren perturbar**)
>
> Me incitan a gritar (**Ellos buscan pincharme para que hable y lamente**)
>
> Soy como una roca (**pero no hablo, soy fuerte y silencioso como una**
> **roca**)
>
> Palabras no me tocan (**las palabras no me hieren, no me enfadan**)
>
> Adentro hay un volcán (**pero por dentro soy como un volcán**)
>
> Que pronto va a estallar ( **que se encuentra a punto de estallar**)
>
> Yo quiero estar tranquilo (**deseo que no me molesten**)
>
> Es mi situación (**estoy en un estado**)
>
> Una desolación (**de tristeza y desamparo**)
>
> Soy como un lamento (**estoy quejándome**)
>
> Lamento boliviano (**es la forma de decir, estoy en una queja continua**
> **por este amor**)
>
> Que un día empezó ( **un día la conocí y comencé a sufrir**)
>
> Y no va a terminar ( **nunca podré desligarme de ella)**
>
> Y a nadie hace daño ( **ya que a nadie molesto, porque lo llevo en mi**
> **interior**)
>
> Uoh, io, io, io-uoh-oh, (**se puede interpretar como "yo lloro"**)
>
> ye-eh-eh-eh, yeh-eh
>
> Y yo estoy aquí
>
> Borracho y loco
>
> Y mi corazón idiota
>
> Siempre brillará (Siempre brillará)
>
> Y yo te amaré
>
> Te amaré por siempre
>
> Nena, no te peines en la cama (**Chica, no te peines, no te tumbes, no estés, utilices o muestres tus habilidades tanto en la cama**)
>
> Que los viajantes se van a atrasar (**que los hombres o tus conquistas**
> **van hacer cola y retrasar**)
>
> Uoh, io, io, io-uoh-oh, ye-eh-eh-eh, yeh-eh
>
> Y hoy estoy aquí
>
> Borracho y loco (**embriagado y loco por tu amor**)
>
> Y mi corazón idiota (**mi tonto corazón**)
>
> Siempre brillará (Siempre brillará)
>
> Y yo te amaré (**aún te amará**)
>
> Te amaré por siempre (**siempre te seguiré queriendo a pesar de todo**)
>
> Nena, no te peines en la cama (**Chica, no utilices tanto tus habilidades en la cama**)
>
> Que los viajantes se van a atrasar (**que los chicos van a tener que
> en cola esperar**)
>
> Y yo estoy aquí
>
> Borracho y loco
>
> Y mi corazón idiota
>
> Siempre brillará (Siempre brillará)
>
> Y yo te amaré
>
> Te amaré por siempre
>
> Nena, no te **pe**i**nes** en la cama
>
> Que los viajantes se van a atrasar

**P.D.**

**Peinar(se)**

- IV.   1.  intr. prnl. Ch. Lucirse alguien, demostrar su habilidad o conocimientos de algo. pop.
- VI.   1.  tr. Ho, ES. Realizar el coito. vulg.

Diccionario de americanismos

https://www.asale.org/damer/peinar

De todas formas, quizás no tenga un significado concreto, ni dentro ni fuera de la canción, aunque me inclino por estas dos últimas acepciones del "Diccionario de americanismos", "**Nena, no te peines en la cama que los viajantes se van a atrasar**", una manera muy sutil de decir que a la nena le gustaba mucho el sexo con todos y por eso el pobre hombre estaba destrozado, pues **es la única razón**, solo en mi opinión, **que explica el cambio abrupto y aparentemente sin sentido de una letra muy uniforme**. Espero en general haya ayudado a tener una visión general de algunos conceptos complejos del propio idioma.

Comment: Hola, Diego, muchísimas gracias por haber tomado el tiempo para ayudarme a entender la canción. Debido a su ayuda, ahora puedo apreciar las letras cuando escucho esta melodía. Y poder apreciarlas completamente me hace sentir muy bien! Muchas gracias a Usted otra vez 

Comment: ¡Hola Maurice! No hay de que, gracias a ti, siempre a tu disposición.

Comment: Yo no te di el -1. Las definiciones de peinarse no se ajustan al contexto, son más o menos lo que dice la gente de fuera de argentina que no conoce el dialecto. Lo único claro es que ambas frases tienen que ver con GGM (personaje Santiago Nassar) aunque no sea oficial.

Comment: Hola cocteau, tu no me diste -1 pero yo si se quien me lo dio, no te preocupes. Yo solo expongo tres teorías que circulan más una cuarta que añadí. En cuanto a "Crónica de una Muerte Anunciada" como una de las teorías, hago un paralelismo de las frases del libro con la canción y una interpretación que puede ser cierta o no , aunque como indico, la canción es bastante uniforme y de repente saltan unas frases que aparentan no tener nada que ver, a eso se une que los autores nunca se han pronunciado. Quizás lleves razón y solo tenga que ver con Gabriel García Márquez. Gracias por tu comentario.